# How can I tell if a variable does not end in a hyphen?

Tags: c#

I have c# variables such as

```
var a = "ABC";
a = "def-";
a = "-";
```

Is there some simple test I could do so I could check if the variable does not end in a hyphen?

```
if ( xxx )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (a.ToString().EndsWith("-")) ...
```

after feedback from Lloyd concerning nulls adapted to

```
if ((a!=null) && (a.ToString().EndsWith("-"))) ...
```

Comment: Why `.ToString()`? -- if it isn't a string it probably doesn´t end in a hyphen?

Comment: ToString() is not necessary as the variable is already a string.

Comment: That's great. Thanks I didn't realize there was and EndsWith. Thanks,

Comment: In the examples shown, a is a String - in this case ToString() is redundant. Since a was declared as var a=... not String a=... I assumed this should work for all data types that have a string representation.

Comment: Additionally: For a string ToString() is a noop, so the performance penalty is neglegable

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty) would be more appropriate as it saves the second comparison, assuming the compiler optimizes it as such.

Answer (score 1):

"Does not end"

```
if (!(a.EndsWith("-"))){
  // Do something
}
```

Doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

*Warning. This may be an editorial*

Revisit your design.

The question has code-smell all over it. I infer that the embedded hyphen has some "business meaning." Such a thing should be embodied as a class, field, property, etc. Such a *properly* named thing will convey it's meaning/intent. But the more important issue is maintainability.

Just yesterday I ran into this in our own code. Hear me now and believe me later. Encoding variable names may seem expedient but you're just setting yourself up for a world of hurt when it comes time to modify it or simply helping the next poor coder understand it.

At the very least, if you insist on encoding variable names, separate that encode/decode into an independent class. And for g0d's sake don't name that class/methods "EncodeName" or the like!!